# SharedPreferences not working when Activity is started from somewhere else?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I have a ThreadActivity with two functions, saveContacts and loadContacts. They both use sharedpreferences and Gson to save an ArrayList consisting of Objects called SimpleContacts. Somehow it cannot retrieve data from sharedpreferences once I start the Activity from somewhere else. (I tried loading instantly after saving and that works, but not if I close the Activity and re-open it)

The save function:

```kotlin
private fun saveContact() {
        val gson = Gson()
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)
        try {
            val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
            val json = gson.toJson(participants)
            editor.putString(threadId.toString()+"_Contact", json)
            editor.apply()
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
}
```

The load function:

```kotlin
private fun loadContact() {
        val gson = Gson()
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)
        val type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<SimpleContact?>?>() {}.type
        try {
            val json = sharedPreferences.getString(threadId.toString()+"_Contact", "")
            participants = gson.fromJson(json, type)
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
}
```

I have 2 Activities that can open this ThreadActivity, if I start it from the same one, it all works perfectly fine. But when I use the other Activity to start it, the sharedPrefs are empty.

Launch Activity that works (I don't know if its because its the way the Intent is build so I will write them both here):

```kotlin
private fun launchThreadActivity(phoneNumber: String, name: String) {
        hideKeyboard()
        val text = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT) ?: ""
        val numbers = phoneNumber.split(";").toSet()
        val number = if (numbers.size == 1) phoneNumber else Gson().toJson(numbers)
        Intent(this, ThreadActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(THREAD_ID, getThreadId(numbers))
            putExtra(THREAD_TITLE, name)
            putExtra(THREAD_TEXT, text)
            putExtra(THREAD_NUMBER, number)

            if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND && intent.extras?.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) == true) {
                val uri = intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)
                putExtra(THREAD_ATTACHMENT_URI, uri?.toString())
            } else if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE && intent.extras?.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) == true) {
                val uris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Uri>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)
                putExtra(THREAD_ATTACHMENT_URIS, uris)
            }

            startActivity(this)
        }
}
```

Start Activity that does not work:

```kotlin
Intent(this, ThreadActivity::class.java).apply {
                        putExtra(THREAD_ID, (it as Conversation).threadId)
                        putExtra(THREAD_TITLE, it.title)
                        putExtra("fromMain", true)
                        startActivity(this)
}
```

Comment: It would be a different SharedPreferences entry if the passed in thread ID is different. And I see you're retrieving the threadId value two different ways in your two Activities. Are you expecting them to always return the exact same value in both cases? Would have to see both implementations (`getThreadId(numbers: Set<String>)` vs. `Conversation.threadId`) to be able to help with debugging that.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was my mistake.
When saveContact was called the threadId was not initialized yet. So basically the keys were always different.

Comment: In case you didn't already do this, setting a breakpoint in `loadContact` and then debugging the app would have let you inspect your variables and step through each line to see what's going on. Always worth a try when doing things one way works, but another way doesn't - something has to be different! And debugging is the easiest way to poke around and see what's up

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).